# Unpivot based on a group of text and two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this toy dataset, which contains text, dates and a columnar group:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'text':['Oh no Monday','Oh no Monday','Gotcha !',
                           'Coffee, please','Coffee, please','Mails '],
                   'dates':['2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000','2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000',
                           '2019-05-25T19:40:43+0000','2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000',
                           '2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000','2019-04-10T19:50:49+0000'],
                   'group':['meme','humour','gif','gif','pic','meme'],
                   'theme':['light','light','funny','dark','dark','funny']})
df
    id  text            dates                       group   theme
0   1   Oh no Monday    2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000    meme    light
1   2   Oh no Monday    2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000    humour  light
2   3   Gotcha !        2019-05-25T19:40:43+0000    meme    funny
3   4   Coffee, please  2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000    gif     dark
4   5   Coffee, please  2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000    gif     sad
5   6   Mails         2019-04-10T19:50:49+0000    meme    funny
```

I want a column for each group and theme with a flag value (1 or 0). This is the expected table:

```
    id  text            dates                       meme humour gif light funny dark sad
0   1   Oh no Monday    2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000    1    1      0    1    0     0    0    
2   3   Gotcha !        2019-05-25T19:40:43+0000    1    0      0    0    1     0    0
3   4   Coffee, please  2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000    0    0      1    0    0     1    1
5   6   Mails         2019-04-10T19:50:49+0000    1    0      0    0    1     0    0
```

I have tried this, but it's wrong:

```
df.pivot(index='id',columns=['group','theme'],values=['group','theme'])

    group   theme
group   meme    humour  gif pic meme    meme    humour  gif pic meme
theme   light   light   funny   dark    dark    funny   light   light   funny   dark    dark    funny
id                                              
1   meme    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN light   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN humour  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN light   NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN gif NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN funny   NaN NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN gif NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN dark    NaN NaN
5   NaN NaN NaN NaN pic NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN dark    NaN
6   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN meme    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN funny
```

There is something wrong in my logic. Please, could you help me or suggest a step to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_dummies` to convert `group` and `theme` into one hot vectors, and then aggregate as needed:

```
pd.concat([
    pd.get_dummies(df.drop('id', 1), columns=['group', 'theme'])
      .groupby(['text', 'dates']).max(), 
    df.groupby(['text', 'dates'])['id'].first()
], 1).reset_index()

             text                     dates  group_gif  group_humour  group_meme  group_pic  theme_dark  theme_funny  theme_light  id
0  Coffee, please  2019-03-30T14:41:20+0000          1             0           0          1           1            0            0   4
1      Gotcha !  2019-05-25T19:40:43+0000          1             0           0          0           0            1            0   3
2         Mails   2019-04-10T19:50:49+0000          0             0           1          0           0            1            0   6
3    Oh no Monday  2019-05-30T17:48:45+0000          0             1           1          0           0            0            1   1
```

Comment: Thank you @Psidom, it worked fine! I was going to mention the aggregation and pipe step (the later is new for me, but I'm going to investigate, seems a powerful function) but you edited your answer, which gets rid of the `group_gif,gif` column for example. Hope you have a great weekend, and again, thank you!